# ¿Cómo guardar un archivo codificado en base 64?

Tags: php, base64

no se mucho de programación pero lo que estoy haciendo es:
Voy a estar recibiendo pdf convertidos en base64 y lo que quiero es decodificarlos para guardarlos, estoy haciendo unas pruebas en local esto es lo que tengo:

```
funcion subirDocumento()
{
      $file = file_get_contents('C:\Users\Desarrollo\Downloads\documento.pdf');

    $base64_pdf = base64_encode($file);

    $base64_decode = base64_decode($base64_pdf);
    $pdf = fopen('prueba_pdf.pdf','w');
    fwrite($pdf, $base64_decode);
    fclose($pdf);
}
```

Una vez que tenga el pdf decodificado quisiera guardarlo.
Al correrlo no hace nada, me podrían decir que me hace falta

Comment: solo agrega `$pdf = fopen('prueba_pdf.pdf','wb');`

Answer (score 0):

En apariencia parece estar bien, creo que el error está en:

```
fwrite($pdf, $base64_decode);
```

Aquí seguro que si escribes un string en lugar de $base64_decode te va a escribir en el archivo sin problema; la cuestión es que por la estructura que tienes base64 es un pdf, un archivo que seguramente no interprete como string. Prueba a devolver el tipo de $base64_decode para ver si es un string.

Por lo demás el código parece no contener errores.